# How comes my channel.basicConsume does not wait for messages

Tags: java-8, rabbitmq, message-queue

Whenever I start the following code:

```
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost("localhost");
    Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
    String exchangeName = "direct_logs";
    channel.exchangeDeclare(exchangeName, "direct");
    String queueName = channel.queueDeclare().getQueue();
    channel.queueBind(queueName, exchangeName, "red");
    channel.basicQos(1);

    final Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel){
        @Override
        public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag,
                                   Envelope envelope,
                                   AMQP.BasicProperties properties,
                                   byte[] body) throws IOException{
            String message = new String(body, "UTF-8");
            System.out.println(message);
            System.out.println("message received");
        }
    };

    channel.basicConsume(queueName, true, consumer);
```

It does not start an endless loop, as is implied in the documentation. Instead, it stops right away.
The only way I can have it consume for some time is to replace `channel.basicConsume` with a loop, as follows:

```
    DateTime startedAt = new DateTime();
    DateTime stopAt = startedAt.plusSeconds(60);
    long i=0;
    try {
        while (stopAt.compareTo(new DateTime()) > 0) {
            channel.basicConsume(queueName, true, consumer);
            i++;
        }
    }finally {
        System.out.println(new DateTime());
        System.out.println(startedAt);
        System.out.println(stopAt);
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

There must be a better way to listen to messages for a while, correct? What am I missing?
It stops listening right away.

Comment: Don't you have any exception such as ConnectException : Connection refused ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you sure it's stopping? What `basicConsume` does is register a consumer to listen to a specific queue so there is no need to execute it in a loop. You only execute it once, and the `handleDelivery` method of the instance of `Consumer` you pass will be called whenever a message arrives.

The Threads that the rabbitmq library creates should keep the JVM from exiting. In order to exit the program you should actually call `connection.close()`

Here is a complete receiver example from rabbitmq: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tutorials/blob/master/java/Recv.java

It's actually pretty much the same as yours.

Answer (score 4):

i had the same issue. the reason was that i was calling connection.close at the end. however, the basicConsume() method does not block on the current thread, rather on other threads, so the code after it, i.e. the connection.close() is called immediately.